# Angular 2, Observable : http.post, http.get

Tags: http, angular, typescript, observable

I have a few problems concerning Http.post and Http.get with 
Observables. I'm a student and I'm trying to write a simple WebApp and 
a Server.

I want to post a boolean on my Server if I press a button. The post 
process does work but everytime I press the button I subscribe another time to the observable. I had the same problem with my http.get method and resolved the problem with this code.

```
getdata() {   
if(this.subscribtion2 === null){
        this.isValid = false;
      this.subscribtion2 = this.service.get2().subscribe(

         daten => {
            this.jsonobj = daten;
            this.message = 
                [
                this.jsonobj.data.message1,
                ];
            console.log('subscribe')
            ;
            this.myModelneu = this.message[0];     
             },     
         err => this.handleError(err),
         () => console.log('Simple GET completed')
            );

    }else
   {
       this.isValid = true;
       console.log('unsubscribe')
       this.subscribtion2.unsubscribe();
       this.subscribtion2 = null;

   }
}
```

The get2() method is in a different class.

```
  get2() {


        return Observable.interval(3000)
          .switchMap(() => this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:3000/daten/2'))
          .map(res => res.json())

  }
```

I don't think that is the common way but I can't find another. 
My http.post look likes this :

```
post(json: boolean) {
      console.log('post executed');
      console.log(JSON.stringify(json));

     return this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:3000/login', { json })
     .subscribe();

   }
```

I tried to understand the tutorials with Observables but I did not find 
how to post data on the server without subscribing to the Observable.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The `http` calls, specifically `get` and `post` return an observable that completes with the result, hence you don't need to unsubscribe. On completion the subscription is terminated.

Comment: That was exactly my thought, but how do you explain. That if I try the getdata() method without the if loop multiple times. I have multiple services that try to get the data everey 3 seconds? I tried it in the browser and it was exactly like that...

Comment: Because the interval generates a new call every 3000 ms. Either do: `Observable.timeout(3000)` (one time delay) or `Observable.interval(3000).take(1)`

Comment: But this wouldn't work. Perhaps my explanation is not good enough. I have an WebApp and a Server. The WebApp runs in the Browser and the Server on VisualCode. On the Server I have changing data which belongs to a car (dummy). I have a flipswitch on the html from the WebApp which should turn on and off the communication between the server and the webapp. If I turn on the flipswitch I subscribe to an observable which receives data from the server every 3 s. If I switch it of the observable should be canceld. Without the if loop I would creat a new observable every time. Is there another way.

Comment: So you want an interval trigger which has a switch? Why not create a single interval and filter it? Observable.interval(3000).filter(v => fetchData).switchMap(...) . This way if you turn the fetchData off, the calls will not be dispatched

Comment: I'm not really used to work with observables  and also a newbie sorry for that.... How is the fetchData connected to the http.get, is the oberservable cancelled if I 'turn off' the 'fetchData' and how do I do it... :)?

Comment: My WebApp should display the data from the Server if the user wants it. The data on the server changes when a request takes place (It's just an easy example of the speed of a real car). Therefore I thought that a interval which I can start and stop is a good idea.